# What's with the odd font used by spammers? How do they do it?

Tags: css, fonts

The screenshot below is from my Gmail spam folder. Notice that some of the email from and subject lines look normal, while many of them appear to use some sort of serif font:

[image: Gmail spam folder showing some emails with an odd serif font]

I'm a web developer, and from poking around, there's no CSS font declarations that are causing this to happen. The only hint is that the inspection panel for the "ZippyLoan ." sender shows that the fonts being used are not just Google's typical Roboto, but also "Cambria Math" (despite there being no corresponding "Cambria Math" CSS font declaration):

[image: Chrome Dev Tools inspection panel]

In fact, it seems that the font definition is somehow built-in to the text, since it even maintains the same appearance in plain-Jane Windows Notepad:

[image: Regular Windows Notepad, showing two fonts.]

Actually, here, I think it works anywhere... play around with it yourself it you'd like:

.

$  !

❤️    $50 /®   (     )

Whiskey Tango Foxtrot. O.o

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not a different font - it's the same font, just using odd code points. For example, the  in  has a code point of 119937:

```js
console.log(''.codePointAt());
```

which [corresponds to](https://unicodelookup.com/#math/2):

> mathematical bold italic capital z  0352201 119937  0x1D481 𝒁

There are many such odd code points that can be used. It's not ASCII.

In contrast, the standard capital Z has a code point of 90:

```js
console.log('Z'.charCodeAt());
```

Comment: Does this mean that we could avoid / block spam by detecting these characters?

Comment: To an extent, but you'd also be blocking legitimate messages sent by people who might have thought they were being cute by using different text formatting. I could see it factoring into a heuristic, at least.